# Ошибка сегментирования NASM

Tags: nasm, elf

Делал подпрограмму для NASM, которая должна была считать длину строки ну и собственно выводить её. Код взял из видео, но у меня ошибка. Код такой:

```
  _strlen:

push rdx
xor rdx,rdx
_strlen_loop_start:

    cmp  [rax+rdx] ,byte  0
    je _strlen_loop_end
    inc rdx
    jmp _strlen_loop_start

_strlen_loop_end:
    pop rdx
    ret



_print:

push rax
push rcx
push rbx
push rdx
mov rcx, rax

call _strlen


mov rdx,rax
mov rax,4
mov rbx,1
int 80h

pop rdx
pop rcx
pop rbx
pop rax
ret

  segment .text
      global _start 
  segment .data
       hell: db  'hell!', 0xA

  _start:

    mov rax,hell
    call _print

    mov rax,1
    mov rbx,0 
    int 0x80
```

Не кидайте тапками, если ответ простой, я действительно не понимаю, что не так.
P.S. NASM version 2.15.04, sys- Arch x86_64

Comment: А что у вас функция _strlen делает ? по моему ничего. она сохраняет rdx, считает в нем длину строки и перед выходом восстанавливает rdx. Т.е. rdx возвращается к своему изначальному состоянию. Возникает вопрос, а зачем в нем что то считали ? И даже если бы она вернула длину, то следующая операция после call (mov) все равно затерла результат. Помимо этого _print перемешивает значения регистров потому что push/pop не зеркальны. И подозреваю, что раз уже как минимум 3 явно бросающиеся в глаза ошибки, есть еще с куча других

Comment: Большое спасибо