# Как скомпилить NASM

Tags: nasm, x86-64, elf

Недавно задавал вопрос про [ошибку сегментирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178212/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-nasm). Нашлись проблемы в коде, но их решения не дало результата. Полез в инет и понял, что любой онлайн IDE для 64 битного NASM-а компилит код без проблем (https://ideone.com/4lmPcD или https://tio.run/#assembly-nasm). Вопрос: почему у меня выдает ошибку?

`nasm -f elf64 prog.asm ld -m elf_x86_64`

`NASM version 2.15.04`
`Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.8.7-arch1-1`

Код:

```
_strlen:
    
    push rdx
    xor rdx,rdx
    _strlen_loop_start:

        cmp  [rax+rdx] ,byte  0
        je _strlen_loop_end
        inc rdx
        jmp _strlen_loop_start

    _strlen_loop_end:
        mov rax,rdx
        pop rdx
        ret



_print:

    push rax
    push rbx
    push rcx
    push rdx
    mov rcx, rax
    
    call _strlen
    
    mov rdx,rax
    mov rax,4
    mov rbx,1
    int 80h

    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rbx
    pop rax
    ret

segment .text
global _start 
segment .data
hell: db  'hell!', 0xA ,0

_start:
    
    mov rax,hell
    call _print

    mov rax,1
    mov rbx,0 
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Вроде как не бонтон использовать int 80h на архитектуре amd64? По крайней мере, strace это сбивает с толку.

Comment: Результат не меняется

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить `main:` перед `_start:`:

```
segment .data
hell: db  'hell!', 0xA ,0

segment .text
global main 
global _start 

main: ; standard gcc entry point
_start:
```

Comment: Не помогло, результат тот же

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию об ошибке.

Comment: Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
При компиляции, указанной в описании
Если делать elf32 то такая:
wrstr.asm:7: error: impossible combination of address sizes
wrstr.asm:7: error: invalid effective address
стр.7 - cmp  [rax+rdx] ,byte  0

Comment: Поправил ответ, проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: К сожалению ничего(

Answer (score 0):

Использование int 80h для системных вызовов ядра Linux давно (думаю, в районе десяти лет как) deprecated и для x86, и для amd64 архитектур. Вместо него для x86 используется sysenter, а для amd64 — syscall.

Номера системных вызовов находятся в [arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl)

Семантика вызова для amd64: все параметры в регистрах; номер вызова (из предыдущего абзаца) в RAX, параметры в RDI, RSI, RDX, R10, R8[, R9]. Возврат: в RAX возвращаемое значение, RCX и R11 портятся, остальные регистры сохраняются.